# JSON weird format access data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is a JSON snip that is created in WooCommerce by a plugin that adds some metadata. I cannot change the formatting of this JSON because it is generated by a plugin. The problem is that the keys and the values are added in a weird way. I am iterating through the line_items and statically referencing this data which I don't want to do, I would like to know if there is a smart way to reference for example:
"key": "_cpo_product_id",
"value": "3572",
if this was formatted correctly it would be: "_cpo_product_id": "3572" and not have "value" as a key, and it would be accessed by: foo.line_items[i]._cpo_product_id
but with this configuration I am a bit lost, I am sure there is an easy way to find the value for a specific key. I am doing this on Google app scripts, but a solution in JavaScript should suffice.

JSON snip:

```
"line_items": [
        {
            "id": 749,
            "name": "Dune",
            "product_id": 3572,
            "variation_id": 0,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_class": "",
            "subtotal": "149.54",
            "subtotal_tax": "31.40",
            "total": "149.54",
            "total_tax": "31.40",
            "taxes": [
                {
                    "id": 24,
                    "total": "31.403148",
                    "subtotal": "31.403148"
                }
            ],
            "meta_data": [
                {
                    "id": 11919,
                    "key": "_cpo_product_id",
                    "value": "3572",
                    "display_key": "_cpo_product_id",
                    "display_value": "3572"
                },
                {
                    "id": 11920,
                    "key": "_add-to-cart",
                    "value": "3572",
                    "display_key": "_add-to-cart",
                    "display_value": "3572"
                },
```

Comment: You can simply `line_items.meta_data.find(({ key, value }) => key === "_cpo_product_id" && value === "3572");` alternatively you could map the meta_data array to refactor the objects, but arguably they would then be harder to search for.

Comment: I want to find the value for a specific key, not specify both parameters

Comment: then just `find()` by key and access the value. `line_items[0].meta_data.find(({ key }) => key === "_cpo_product_id")?.value;`. Possibly read up on [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)